# Is it possible to adjust the height of the boxes plot of gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Following is the data.csv

```
#x,data
0,20
1,30
2,40
3,50
```

The following code uses gnuplot to plot the boxes plot and saves to png

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot','-p'], 
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        encoding='utf8'
                        )

proc.communicate(
f"""
set terminal png size 400,300; set output 'plot.png';
set boxwidth 1
set style fill solid 1.0 
set xrange [-1:40]
set datafile separator comma 
plot 'data.csv' using 1:2 with boxes notitle

"""
)
```

The output png image:

[image: The output png is]

Is it possible to modify the height of each box and set it to 10?

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little? You want to make the shortest box of certain height, or you want the boxes to start at a certain height below where they end?

Comment: @MatiasAgelvis I've edited the question to include the expected output. The input data will always be a multiple of a number. In this case it is 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this script adapted from [Object placement using a data file](http://www.gnuplotting.org/object-placement-using-a-data-file/), by the great Hagen Wierstorf.

```sh
reset

# The range has to be set manually
set xrange [-1:5]
set yrange [10:70]

set datafile separator comma

set style rectangle dashtype solid fc rgb "#0077ff" fillstyle solid noborder

# Rectangle dimensions
height = 10
width = 1

# --- Read placement from data file
# Set the output of the following plot to a table in order to achieve that it is
# not shown in the current terminal
set table '/dev/null'
# Function to create the right call function
add_rectangle(x,y,hgt,wdt) = sprintf(\
    ' set object rect from "%f", "%f" to "%f", "%f"; ',x,y,x+wdt,y+hgt)
# Initialize command string
CMD = ''
# Do a dummy plot to read the position data
plot 'data.csv' u 1:(CMD = CMD.add_rectangle($1,$2,height,width))
# Execute the drawing command
eval(CMD)
# Restore the terminal
unset table

# dummy empty plot to create the plot instance
plot x with line linecolor rgb"#ffffff" notitle
```

You can get this plot

[image: Plot]

As far has I know you can't circumvent setting the plot ranges manually, but since you are using a python script to invoke the plot maybe you can pass the min and max of the columns to the script and automate the setup.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, there is the plotting style `with boxxyerror`, check `help boxxyerror`.
However, from your question and your sketch and your given data it is not fully clear whether you want

- 3 boxes; from one datapoint to the next (i.e. height = difference between two consecutive datapoints)
- 4 boxes; starting from the data value with fixed height 10.

**Code:** (second  option)

```
### plot boxes with defined height
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#x,data
0,20
1,30
2,40
3,50
EOD

set xrange [-1:40]
set datafile separator comma
set style fill solid 1.0
plot $Data u 1:2:($1-0.5):($1+0.5):2:($2+10) w boxxyerror notitle

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]